# How do I scale the font size in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, size

[image]

How do I scale the font size above?

Answer (score 7):

Click on `File -> Settings -> Editor` and check the field: `Change font-size with CRTL + Mouse Wheel` and the press control and adjust font size using mouse wheel!

Answer (score 1):

For MacBook Users:

To change font size:

1. Select **Android Studio** menu (which is present next to Apple icon)
2. Preferences
3. Editor
4. Font
5. Size(give size)-->ok

To zoom in and out in Editor:

1. Select **Android Studio** menu
2. Editor
3. General
4. change font size (zoom) with command and mouse wheel-->ok